# How can I click on one image using the onclick event and have it change another image on the same webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

The user is supposed to click one of three images, either rock, paper or scissors and when they click on one of these three choices, it changes an image to the right of these 3 images to that of a hand making that shape as you would see in a game of rock, paper, scissors. I can't seem to figure out how to set the onclick event to change the image to the right of the image that is clicked on. Here is a sample of my code.

(HTML)

```
<tr>
  <td onclick="clickRock()" id="rockClick"><img src="rock.jpg" alt="Rock"></td>      
  <td rowspan="3" id="change1"><img src="leftPaperHand.jpg" alt="Left Hand" height="350"></td>       
  <td rowspan="3" id="change2"><img src="rightRockHand.jpg" alt="Right Rock" height="350"></td>
</tr>
```

(javaScript)

```
 function clickRock(args) {
   img= document.getElementById("change1");
   img.src="leftRockHand.jpg"
 }
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

Comment: the problem is that the element with the id of "change1" is actually the `td` element that is the parent of the image. Try moving `id="change1"` from the `td` to the `img` element inside of it.

Comment: If you stepped through your code with a debugger and examined the value of the `img` variable, you would see that it is not the `img` element you thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

The function written like this would work. This way you put a target image id as the first parameter and the image that you would like to replace it with as the second.

```
function clickRock( targetImg, chgeImg ) {
    document.getElementById(targetImg).src = changeIng;
}

document.getElementById("rockClick").addEventListener("click", clickRock( "change2", "myNewImage.jpg") );
```

Then you would take the onClick out of you HTML. This is not that flexible. That could be worked in if I had more details on what you are trying to do.